# Erasing boundaries between polygons that are next to each other using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, dissolve

I have files that representes individual houses and blocks. I want to have a file that represents a residential area in a block.

Is there a way to erase the line, boundaries, between polygons that are adjacent?

Comment: Sounds like you want to `dissolve` or `merge` the polygons.

Comment: In ARC/INFO this was possible on-the-fly using DROPLINES, which is a function I have not found in ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro.  Dissolve remains the workaround there.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it worked! Thanks @csk

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has two tools to remove boundaries between adjacent (touching) polygons:

1. `Dissolve` tool (Processing toolbox > Vector geometry).

[image]

- The `dissolve` tool will combine all polygons into a single multipolygon feature. You can use the `multipart to singleparts` tool to split non-adjacent polygons into single-part features.
- Attributes will be lost. After running `multipart to singlepart`, You can use the `join attributes by location` tool to add the original attributes back to the polygons.

  2. `Merge Selected Features` tool (Advanced Digitizing toolbar).

[image]

- Select two or more adjacent polygons. Click the `merge selected features` button. Choose what happens to the original attributes (eg, you can concatenate text strings, perform mathematical functions on numerical values, or manually enter a specific value).
- The downside with this method is that you have to handle each group of polygons separately, so it takes longer than the `dissolve` method.

[image]